# How do I add a newline before each non-ascii word in Sublime-Text2?

Tags: regex, csv, sublimetext2, replace

I have a poorly formatted csv file of Korean words with English definitions. I'd like to add a new line before each Korean word. For example:

```
# I'd like to change this
하다,to do,크기,size,대기,on hold,

# Into this
하다,to do,
크기,size,
대기,on hold,
```

Using the regex ([^\x00-\x7F]*) I was able to highlight all instances of Korean words but when I try to replace them with \n$1 it works only for the first word after my last cursor position and then inserts a newline after each character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `+` instead of `*`, (the former means 1 or more, the latter means 0 or more). Otherwise you get zero-width matches at every position:

```
[^\x00-\x7F]+
```